# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I am getting this error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("4/29/2013", "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: it resolve with DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("4/29/2013", "M/dd/yyyy", null); but what if date is 12/29/2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one `M` instead of `MM` to match the format for months values that are one or two numbers.

The same goes for `d` for days.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("4/29/2013", "M/dd/yyyy", null);

DateTime aDate = DateTime.ParseExact("4/2/2013", "M/d/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: it resolve with DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("4/29/2013", "M/dd/yyyy", null); but what if date is 12/29/2013?

Comment: @AltafSami, can you please explain what is so special in date 12/29/2013, so you think it may cause the problem? For me it looks like as same date as any other, and it matches "M/d/yyyy" format perfectly.

Comment: i was thinking that date 4/29/2013 has format M/dd/yyyy and 12/4/2013 has MM/d/yyyy so it may be not work. this is working i was assuming wrong. thanks